# Nuitka: No module named 'pyfiglet.fonts'

Tags: python-3.x, nuitka

After running

```
python -m nuitka --plugin-enable=pylint-warnings --follow-imports --standalone sample.py
```

it completes the build without any error but when I run the build **sample** file from **sample.dist** directory it gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[PATH TO PROJECT]/sample.dist/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 359, in get_provider
KeyError: 'pyfiglet.fonts'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[PATH TO PROJECT]/sample.dist/yarasilly2.py", line 183, in <module>
  File "[PATH TO PROJECT]/sample.dist/pyfiglet/__init__.py", line 794, in __init__
  File "[PATH TO PROJECT]/sample.dist/pyfiglet/__init__.py", line 801, in setFont
  File "[PATH TO PROJECT]/sample.dist/pyfiglet/__init__.py", line 126, in __init__
  File "[PATH TO PROJECT]/sample.dist/pyfiglet/__init__.py", line 136, in preloadFont
  File "[PATH TO PROJECT]/sample.dist/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1134, in resource_exists
  File "[PATH TO PROJECT]/sample.dist/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 361, in get_provider
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfiglet.fonts'
```

- Nuitka version, full Python version and Platform (Windows, OSX, Linux ...)

  python -m nuitka --version

```
0.6.8.4
Python: 3.8.3 (default, May 29 2020, 00:00:00) 
Executable: [PATH TO PROJECT]/venv/bin/python
OS: Linux
Arch: x86_64
```

- Nuitka Install

```
pip install nuitka
```

- Sample piece of code

```
from pyfiglet import Figlet
if __name__ == '__main__':
  f = Figlet(font='slant')
   puts(colored.blue(f.renderText("Sample Text")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code in the jupter notebooks

! pip install pyfiglet

Input the above code before you start your work..!
Let me know if that works....
And also support me, that brings motivation for further.

Comment: Also check out this link...... https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka

Comment: Why do I need Jupyter Notebook for this? And I have already know the Nuitka GithubRepo anything special you want me to look into.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem and after reading [the user](https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka#use-case-4---program-distribution) guide I found a solution.

```
python -m nuitka --plugin-enable=pylint-warnings --follow-imports --standalone sample.py --include-package=pyfiglet --include-data-dir={PATH-TO-PYFIGLET-LIB}=pyfiglet
```